# Does it matter if main( ) creates an NSAutoreleasePool and drains it before exit?

Tags: cocoa, memory-management, nsautoreleasepool

Because if `main()` creates an `NSAutoreleasePool`, and drains it before the program exits, then even though it can prevent memory leaks,  the whole process's memory space is going to be freed up next anyway -- does it matter if we free up little pieces if the whole piece is freed up next?  In fact, if it keeps on working on the small pieces, won't it cause the program to exit slower?

(`drain` can invoke `release`, which in turn invoke `dealloc`, but if `dealloc` is only to free up memory but nothing else (such as closing a file), then the `drain` won't help freeing up memory)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's considered good practice to clean up after yourself where possible, rather than relying on the environment to do it for you. If all you're worried about is memory usage, then no, the topmost pool isn't strictly necessary--but that's *not* the only thing you need to consider. Objects may do things other than free memory in their `-dealloc` methods (e.g. flushing files to disk, releasing rare OS resources, or freeing up resources that aren't otherwise returned to the system on process exit.)

Not to mention the console spam when objects get autoreleased without a pool present.

Comment: Apple strongly discourages the use of `dealloc` for anything other than freeing memory. Scarce resources should be handled by the application's delegate, in the `applicationWillTerminate:` method (or whatever it's called).

Comment: That's not the correct location at all. If an object wraps a scarce resource (e.g. a `FileHandle` or `SharedMemory` or `KernelThingy` class), it is responsible for disposing of that resource when done. The application delegate is responsible for freeing up application-wide resources, not object-wide resources.

Comment: There is no promise that `dealloc` will be run at application termination time (and it generally isn't). There is a promise that `applicationWillTerminate:` will run, as well as that the equivalent notification will be posted.

Comment: This is true. That's why classes like `NSStream` and `NSFileHandle` have `-close` and `-closeFile` methods, respectively. However, these classes do dispose of their sparse resources on deallocation *anyway*, because deallocation may occur when explicit destruction otherwise does not. (i.e., `-close` is called from within `-dealloc`.) It's all part of building a robust system.

Comment: Sure; we probably don't actually disagree here. I agree with calling these kind of things in dealloc. You just can't *rely* on them being called in `dealloc`, so observing program termination is often required. And the top-level autorelease drain is almost never going to actually call your dealloc. It's still a good thing; no argument.

Comment: so I think in the past, if a file wasn't closed, there was a chance that the last written data wasn't actually in the file?  (maybe that was the PC or UNIX... or Mac), but so is it true that closing of file shouldn't be done in any `dealloc`, but done in `applicationWillTerminate` or in each class's particular exit method.

Comment: @RobNapier: Yeah, I think we're just saying the same thing in different ways. :)

Comment: @SarahW: It's still true. Data isn't written to disk immediately. It's cached in memory, and then in an on-disk cache, to speed up write times. This means that in the right circumstances, the last chunk of data written to the file will never make it there.

Comment: But `exit()` does flush all the buffers to disk. So it's going to write if it doesn't crash. And if it crashes, appWillTerminate won't run either.

Comment: `exit()` isn't guaranteed to be called. I'm only talking about corner cases here.

Answer (score 4):

During program termination of a GUI program, `dealloc` is not called. It's bypassed as a special-case to avoid slowing down shutdown. This is important in case you're relying on `dealloc` being called, since there is no promise that it will be.

The top-level autorelease pool is there so that the system can reliably give you warnings for threads that are missing an autorelease pool (and Jonathan points out). It will never really drain in a GUI program. It will drain in a command-line program, and it could slow down program completion, but that generally isn't a huge problem. If it is in your commandline app, you could move the `exit()` prior of the autorelease pool drain.